Is there a definition for tree rotation?
I might be asking this question because I lack the basic knowledge of rotations. If that is the case, could you suggest any resources for learning it. But I don't think that I am. Every source that I have checked for tree rotation seems to very hand wave and no proper definition is provided for what it means to rotate a tree.
How do we define a right of left rotation of a binary search tree. I understand how to rotate a binary search tree that was made by adding the nodes as 3, 2, 1. But I don't understand how to rotate a tree which was made by adding nodes as 5, 3, 4.
Is there a formal definition of what a tree rotation is?

What about "a bijection of tree nodes with finite recursion depth"? This paper discusses these transformations in great depth. (No pun intended!) It also includes a rigorous definition of "finite recursion depth".

@Trebor I like that defintion. Thank you!

Is there a problem with the explanation given at wikipedia? There it is explained how a node, its child, and their three subtrees are rearranged.
